# java - Debug full screen app in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, macos, fullscreen

I'm developing a java [full screen](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/exclusivemode.html) application. I would like to debug this application using eclipse debugger. However, if I put a breakpoint, my application stops, but my eclipse window doesn't popup, because the full screen application is on.

Up till now, I commented out the lines which made it a full screen application, but I wonder if there is a better solution for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution is 2 screens maybe...? Or if its Windows try alt+tab'ing to Eclipse.

Comment: - 2 screens might be a solution, but for that I would need a second screen... :-)
- it's a mac. (see tag)

Comment: What about putting a line of code to go back to Window mode right before the line with the break point?

Answer (score 2):

Run your app in [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) (if an Intel Mac) and connect remotely with the [debugger](http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-debug-remote-java-applicat).
(Only an idea, never done this).

Answer (score 0):

Simple: go with a [Virtual Desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/5949/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-using-virtual-desktops)

[image: Virutal Desktops]

Put eclipse on one desktop, and your full screen app on another.
Then switch back on the eclipse screen, and wait for the breakpoint to be activated.

Comment: switching to another desktop doesn't seem to work when the full-screen application is running...